# Display Suite View Only Showing Default Display

Tags: display-suite

Custom displays are no longer showing up on the Front-End; instead only the default view is showing. The following message displays next to the template section on the display page (structure/types/manage/contenttype/display/display_name) "This layout is defined in code: disable layout." When I click "Disable Layout" link it takes me to a new page and displays: "This operation is not possible."
What does this error mean? What is the cause? How can it be corrected?

It is not clear whether this error is the reason the display is not showing on the frontend. I have tried accessing the display several different ways include through a view, shows the default (view-mode-full) content display, not the one it is set to. Though the default view is picking up my assigned custom classes.

It is as if Display Suite will not display more than one display on front-end. I can customize and edit "full content" display but this displays on front-end regardless.

Comment: Is this Drupal 8?

Comment: Latest version of DS and Drupal 7.5.1

Comment: All layouts that come with Display Suite are "defined in code".  All these layouts will display the message "This operation is not possible" if you try to disable them. This is not the cause of your error. The fact that the front end is not displaying your custom display is due to another problem. You need to include more information if you want me to try to help. For example, how do you generate your front end? With Views? Blocks? Or simply displaying nodes? A screenshot of the Field UI of the content type may also help.

Comment: @argiepiano I updated original question with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was caused by a conflict with [View Role Per Node Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_mode_per_role)
Even though I did not have any node views assigned based on role, it still seemed to be interfering with the Display Suite behavior.